# ¿Cómo puedo excluir la página principal en una consulta usando la API de Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics

He configurado la API de Google Analytics para usarla en mi servidor con PHP.

A través del siguiente método obtengo las 12 páginas más visitadas hoy, y el total de visitas a esas páginas en los últimos 30 días:

```
function getTopPages($profileId,$analytics) {
    $optParams = array(
            'max-results' => 12,
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        );

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '30daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:pageviews',
       $optParams);

}
```

El problema es que en el resultado obtenido, la página que aparece siempre primero como más visitada es la página principal del dominio, y yo quiero excluirla del informe.

**¿Hay alguna forma de indicarle a la API que ignore la página principal?** Estuve revisando la documentación y no encontré la forma de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usando [`filters`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=es-419#filters) junto con [`ga:pagePath`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath)?, es decir, `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath!%3D/'`

Comment: @Marcos no logro hacerlo. Filtros como este me funcionan: `'filters'       => 'ga:pagePath!~(evangelios/|feature/comentarios-biblicos/)'` ahí me omite el path `evangelios` y el path `feature/comentarios-biblicos`... en cambio, si agrego algo como `|//` o  `|/`  no funciona. No sé cómo aplicar el filtro, ya que la página principal lo único que tiene es esto `/` como path. He recurrido a quitarla del array de resultados con `array_splice`, pero quisiera omitirla de los resultados para no tener luego que quitarla.

Comment: Intenta hacerlo así: `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath!~^/$'` o `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath!~%5E/$'` (que es lo mismo solo que `URI encoded`). ¿O a lo mejor el path es vacio?

Comment: ¡Si @Marcos me funcionó con `^/$`! Propongo que lo pongas como respuesta para dar la pregunta por resuelta. También descubrí que una forma de evitar el primer resultado es poniendo en la variable `$optParams` el siguiente parámetro: `'start-index'=>2`. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo agregando:

- El parámetro de consulta [`filters`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=es-419#filters)

  > El parámetro de cadena de consulta `filters` limita los datos devueltos en la solicitud. Para usar el parámetro `filters`, indica una dimensión o una métrica por la que se filtrará, seguida de la expresión de filtro.
- La dimensión [`ga:pagePath`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath)

  > Una página en el sitio web especificada por ruta y/o parámetros de consulta.
- El operador para dimensiones `!~` (*No coincide con la expresión regular*)
- La expresión regular `^/$`, que significa: "*Empieza (`^`) y termina (`$`) en barra (`/`)*"

#### Ejemplo:

```
function getTopPages($profileId,$analytics) {
    $optParams = array(
        'max-results' => 12,
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath!~^/$',
    );

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '30daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:pageviews',
       $optParams
   );
}
```